# How to fix 'Permission denied' in Docker sh entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh, steam, garrys-mod

I'm trying to create an easy-to-use Docker image for the Garry's Mod server. While my Docker image builds just fine, running it as a container always results in a single error: `/bin/sh: 1: ./easygmod.sh: Permission denied`.

I'm using the `cm2network/steamcmd` image as a base. I have tried both tags that the aforementioned base image has. I have tried `chmod +x`, changing users to `root`, and fiddling with the shebang in the first line of the `easygmod.sh` script, as well as a number of possible typos, particularly in file names and paths.

I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Phyremaster/easy-gmod-docker) for this project which [auto-builds to Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/phyremaster/easy-gmod). Currently, the lines of code involving the problematic script are:

```
# Start main script
ADD easygmod.sh .
RUN chmod +x easygmod.sh
USER steam
CMD ./easygmod.sh
```

Also, the shebang/first line of the script is currently `#!/bin/sh`.

Despite having no logical explanation, the `easygmod.sh` script refuses to be executed, always throwing the error `Permission denied`. This especially confusing given that [my only other public GitHub project](https://github.com/Phyremaster/papermc-docker), which is very similar (similar style Docker image with the same base OS as `cm2network/steamcmd`), never had any issues like this.

Comment: Run `chmod +x easygmod.sh` on the host. Also your adding that file as root as USER is after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file isn't owned by `steam` in the container, so the `chmod +x` was insufficient. Either add `--chown=steam` to the `ADD`, or change your `chmod` from `+x` to `a+rx`.

Also, you didn't specify CWD or a path to put those files in. It's likely that the `root` version of that image has a CWD that `steam` can't access. You should use `/home/steam/` for that instead.

Comment: @Phyremaster I noticed one more thing. Answer updated.